# Intellij Hot Reload doesn't work properly after reload it is unable to find the spring injected bean

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, hot-reload, spring-boot-devtools

I am working with a spring boot project in intelliJ and seems like hot reloading is not working as expected. I have configured the project and IDE so that hot reload should work i.e i have checked build project automatically under settings also in registry i have checked **compiler.automake.allow.when.app.runing** and have added spring boot dev-tools dependency and with these steps intelliJ does hot reload when i change my source code, But i don't see much difference in productivity by saying, that I mean a simple restart server and hot reload is almost working same, also many of the times when hot reload takes place i get bean dependency resolve error

```
`Field courseRepository in com.practice.jpamappings.JpaMappingsApplication required a bean of type 'com.practice.jpamappings.repositories.CourseRepository' that could not be found`.
```

I have checked with the error and it's not related to the missing bean cause when i restart the server everything works fine so does hot reload have to do something with this missing bean error ?

did i configure the hot reload properly ? or i need to do some more efforts to make it work properly.

Comment: Try [spring loaded](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.8.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html#howto-reload-java-classes-without-restarting)

Comment: @Andrey i tried with the dependency but no luck, app stopped hot reloading completely.